# How to un-spherize an image using Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, distortion, projection

Assume I have a traditional panorama. I use a spherize technique (e.g., in Photoshop) to produce a spherical image. Some time later, I want to take the spherical image and get back the landscape (ideally via Photoshop).

Assume I don't have the .pst that was used to create it, only the spherical image file.

Any recommendations on a Photoshop step-by-step to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: By Spherize do you mean Photoshop Filter > Distortion > Spherize? or something else? I'm not sure what you mean by "traditional" panorama, either. Can you possibly post an example image?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, using the Spherize filter to produce a spherical image. Then I want to reverse that to turn the spherical image into a rectangular image.

Comment: This is a possible lesson on "Why you always work on a copy image"....

Comment: I voted to close because "the idea  of "spherize" can refer to a a) spherical projection, b) little planet, c) ultra wide angle, d) or some other effect in photoshop. Post an example image please.

Comment: @Rafael Why voting to close if only some precisions are needed ?

Comment: It is a normal procedure. If a question is improved  it can be re opened. That is when you find an "on hold" question. Yup, probably the button should say "on hold".

Comment: @Rafael "close" and "on hold" are synonymous on SE.  Don't worry about which one you see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pradeep Sekar was in the right direction but is probably using an old version of Photoshop.

Using Photoshop CC, here comes a step-by-step solution :

1. Open your *sphere* image in Photoshop. Here an image from http://photography.tutsplus.com/articles/using-polar-coordinates-to-turn-landscapes-into-planets-and-more--photo-9998 as example :

[image: Unsphere 1]

2. Go to Filter > Distort > Polar Coordinates

[image: Unsphere 2]

3. Select *Polar to Rectangular* and check the preview.

[image: Unsphere 3]

4. You are done. Some adjustments may be needed on the "borders" on your images.

[image: Unsphere 4]

Comment: If you're really brave :-),  you can apply the polar-Cartesian transform with a couple lines of **R** or MATLAB.

Comment: I just want to say that old version of PS wasn't the issue, anyone giving an answer different from this is just lack of experience. Polar Coordinates was one of the original filters.

Answer (score -1):

This is just a theory and has not been tested so I wouldn't know how the output would be.

You try to invert the image 1st and then try the "Photoshop Filter > Distortion > Spherize".

Do submit the results here

Comment: Invert in what way?

Comment: @mattdm : I'm pretty sure pradeep sekar means invert up/down (inverting up/down is a step toward making a *polar* panorama from a landscape image). I don't see how the Distortion > Spherize will help, its goal is to *create* a *spherized* image... BTW, 30s later, I tested it => **not working** :) Link to create a *sphere* image : http://photography.tutsplus.com/articles/using-polar-coordinates-to-turn-landscapes-into-planets-and-more--photo-9998

Comment: Posting "guesses" or "theories" as answers is generally frowned upon.